# Matlab: Explicitly specifying pie graph slice color

Tags: matlab, pie-chart, colormap

I'm creating a pie graph.

```
pie([a,b,c,d]);
```

Is it possible to explicitly change the color of the individual slices?

For example; if I wanted the slices for a and b to always be green and c and d to always be blue, regardless of their size, how would I do that? It seems to me that a color map shades using the size of the slice not necessarily the order in which it was given to the pie function.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The colors of the pie are determined by the axis colormap. So define a matrix with as many rows as the number of pie wedges, and use that as colormap. The first color refers to the first value (`a`), etc.

For example:

```
pie([3 2 4 1])
colormap([1 0 0;      %// red
          0 1 0;      %// green
          0 0 1;      %// blue
          .5 .5 .5])  %// grey
```

[image]