# In matlab 2016b use a colormap to color the slices of a pie chart

Tags: matlab

This seems like it should be a lot easier than it is...

In matlab 2016b, I want to use a colormap to color the slices of a pie chart.

My data are three element vectors and might contain a zero. I have three colors in my colormap that need to be used in the order of the vector data.

For example:

```
data = [1 0 1];
my_cols = [1.0000 0.8398 0; 0.8594 0.0781 0.2344; 0.2539 0.4102 0.8789];
labels = {'','',''};
p = pie(data,labels);
p.Patch = my_cols;
```

I have tried all sorts of ways that have been previously suggested but it seems to not work with version 2016b.

Note that I need the first element of my data to always correspond to the first color in my colormap. I think Matlab colors slices based on size, but I don't want this.

Comment: Which sort of ways have you tried? You should mention those!

Comment: @SardarUsama Sorry, I tired this method http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29858254/matlab-explicitly-specifying-pie-graph-slice-color but it doesn't work

Comment: `pie(data);`
`colormap(my_cols)` no?

Comment: @SardarUsama I get the following error `Subscript indices must either be real positive integers or logicals.`

Comment: Which line does give you that error? By any chance do you have a variable or a function named `pie` and/or `colormap` in your workspace/path which is/are over-shadowing the built-in functions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I do not have 16b at hand. The following was done in 17a:

```
data = [1 0.5 1];
my_cols = [1.0000 0.8398 0; 0.8594 0.0781 0.2344; 0.2539 0.4102 0.8789];
labels = {'','',''};
p = pie(data,labels);
p(1).FaceColor = my_cols(1,:);
p(3).FaceColor = my_cols(2,:);
p(5).FaceColor = my_cols(3,:);
```

Explanation: `pie` returns 2 elements for each slice, the patch object and the corresponding string object. You must set the color for the patch objects, i.e. in your case `p(1)`, `p(3)`, and `p(5)`.

Note that I changed your `data` input. With the zero in the vector you will get a warning and your variable dimensions are off.